# Why can't I move the picture using the first code?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone see any difference between the two code blocks below? The first one doesn't run at all, and the second one works perfectly. Why is that happening?

```
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">

        #stones_image {
            /*border: 1px solid red;*/
            left: 0;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body onload="set_timer()">
    <img src="pics/stones.png" id="stones_image">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var the_timer, x_position = 0, the_image;

        function set_timer() {
            the_image=document.getElementById("stones_image");
            x_position=x_position+1;
            the_image.style.left=x_position;
            the_timer = setTimeout(set_timer, 50);
        }

    </script>
```

And the code that works:

```
<head>
    <script>
        var the_timer, x_position = 0, the_image;

        function set_timer() {
            the_image=document.getElementById("stones_image");
            x_position=x_position+1;
            the_image.style.left=x_position;
            the_timer = setTimeout(set_timer, 50);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="set_timer()">
    <img src="stones.png" id="stones_image"
         style="position:absolute; left:0">
</body>
```

Comment: The first JS code doesn't run because your function `set_timer()` doesn't get fired. Secondly, if it fired, the image wouldn't move because you didn't set any `position` value of the image's CSS.

Comment: Something funny happened, but i still need if someone could please explain it to me. when i removed the !doctype declaration the code run perfectly. with the html5 doctype it doesn't work. why is that? is there any relation between doctype declaration and setTimeout()? may sound stupid but am really confused. Thank you in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code, you never call `set_timer` function, so it will be never executed.

In the second code, `set_timer` is called on document load (with `<body onload="set_timer">`, so it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I can see wrong:

- Position absolute is missing in the 1st one.
  You have to add any `position` except `static` in your styles.
- You have to add `px` with the inject style.
  ex: `the_image.style.left=x_position+**'px'**;`

Comment: But the second one works without px being injected. positioning the image didn't help. I practically copied and pasted the function. i wonder if it is a display problem. it is really nagging me.

Answer (score 0):

It is work:

You forgot write "px" after varible `x_position+"px";`

```js
var the_timer, x_position = 0, the_image;

function set_timer() {
   the_image=document.getElementById("stones_image");
   x_position=x_position+1;
   the_image.style.left=x_position+"px";
   the_timer = setTimeout(set_timer, 50);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="set_timer()">

   <img  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/631986/pexels-photo-631986.jpeg" id="stones_image" style="position:absolute; left:0;width:100%">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="test1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```